# Getting Known Error In Django In model

Tags: django

Model.py

```
   from django.db import models
 class Albums(models.Model):
     artist = models.CharField(max_lenght=250)
     Albums_Name = models.CharField(max_lenght = 500)
     Album_logo = models.CharField(max_lenght = 250)
 class Songs(models.Model):
     albums=models.ForeignKey(Albums,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     file_type = models.CharField(max_lenght = 500)
     Song_title = models.CharField(max_lenght = 500)
```

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Ganaana.apps.GanaanaConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', ]
```

error:
Command using:python manage.py makemigrations Ganaana
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 22, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 364, in execut
    e_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5 
    py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in 
    import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "", line 978, in _gcd_import
    File "", line 961, in _find_and_load
    File "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "", line 655, in _load_unlocked
    File "", line 678, in exec_module
    File "", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "E:\PythonDjango\website\Ganaana\models.py", line 4, in 
    class Albums(models.Model):
    File "E:\PythonDjango\website\Ganaana\models.py", line 5, in Albums
    artist = models.CharField(self,max_lenght = 250)
    NameError: name 'self' is not defined
    PS E:\PythonDjango\website> python manage.py makemigration Ganaana
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 22, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 364, in execut
    e_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in 
    import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "", line 978, in _gcd_import
    File "", line 961, in _find_and_load
    File "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    PS E:\PythonDjango\website> python manage.py makemigration Ganaana
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 22, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 364, in execut
       e_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
      py3.6.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in 
    import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "", line 978, in _gcd_import
    File "", line 961, in _find_and_load
    File "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "", line 655, in _load_unlocked
    File "", line 678, in exec_module
    File "", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "E:\PythonDjango\website\Ganaana\models.py", line 4, in 
    class Albums(models.Model):
    File "E:\PythonDjango\website\Ganaana\models.py", line 5, in Albums
    artist = models.CharField(max_lenght=250)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.5-
    py3.6.egg\django\db\models\fields__init__.py", line 1061, in **init**
    super(CharField, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'
I dont understand my error? I have given a right name still getting error? can anybody identify the error

Comment: You have misspelled ``max_length``` as ```max_lenght```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be `max_length` and not `max_lenght`. Minor typo - please change that in your model and see if it fixes the issue :)